# Exe not being updated after rebuilding the Windows Service

Tags: .net, windows-services, exe

I have  Windows service installed on my local. The service is written using .NET, and it is installed using InstallUtil. I made some changes in the service , stopped the service and then rebuild the project. But for some reason, my exe file is not being updated.In file explorer my exe file still shows the modified date 2022 means it was last updated in 2022.

I have done this before several times but I don't know why this time my exe is not being updated.
Can anyone help me with this?

I have tried to clean my solution, and again rebuild the project as well.

After rebuild, It also shows me the path of the exe.

[image]

Other files are getting updated.
[image]

Comment: What do you mean it "shows date"? Where does it show that date? In File Explorer (Date modified/created/accessed)? Have you check file sizes before and after the update?

Comment: @Christian.K yes in file explorer. The modified date still shows 2022 .However If it is updated it should the current date.

Comment: Can you temporarily rename the output/project/assembly so the exe's name is different?

Comment: @JeremyThompson How can I temporarily rename the output/project/assembly ? You mean the rename my service ?

Comment: No, rename the "old" executable (or move it out of the way), then rebuild. Check if the (new) executable reappears. You might also want to check if your build actually copies the exectuable to the directory you look into.

Comment: @Christian.K I did as you said. Moved the old exe file to some new location and again rebuild, it generated exe file again but the modified date is still old.

Comment: So just to make things clear: We are talking about `D:\EmailServiceForAll\TestService\bin\Release\TestService.exe`. You removed it, rebuilt and got a (new) file with the same modification date?

Comment: @Christian.K Yes the same path. It generated exe but with same old date.

Comment: OK, sorry I have no idea then - other than you accidentally look at some wrong files (which I don't presume).  You could try with an empty / clean "dummy" project and check if last-modified-time is correctly updated there (spoiler: it is). Maybe there is something in the project file that does funny things. Also: are you sure you rebuild in Release (because that is in the directory you seem to expect) mode (I guess you are because you see the file reapper after clean/rebuild)?

Comment: @Christian.K Even in debug mode, still old date

Comment: It's not possible. If you rebuild then it will create a new file with a new DateTime Stamp. Try this, run process monitor (the FileMon part) quickly start it and stop it during a build and see where the exe is getting written, because as Christian & I suspect you're looking in the wrong folder even though you said you delete the files and rebuild...

Comment: @JeremyThompson I am looking in the correct path and I have done this before as well. Only this time, the exe is not being updated. How do I run process monitor?

Comment: @JeremyThompson Also see other files are getting updated with correct date , I have attached a screenshot of all files in that path.

Answer (score 0):

That's an XML Configuration file with the 2022 date not the EXE with the 2023 date!

When projects haven't changed Visual Studio (unless specified with a Project setting) wont compile the project again to inprove compilation/build times and also cause there's no point with no changes.

If an XML file has not changed, why would Visual Studio create a new version, in this situation it appears it uses the old XML file.

TIP: In Windows go to Folder View and choose Unhide File Extensions.

[image]

Comment: I installed my service using this same path that means I did it wrong ? And I have to install the second one . right?